# nhibernate multiple recordsets from stored procedure

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures

Does nHibernate support multiple record-sets returning from an SP, if so can someone show me some basic implementation?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: This may not matter, but which database vendor are you working with?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

[nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-limits-storedprocedures](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-limits-storedprocedures)