# NHibernate stored procedure with multiple result sets

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there any known solution to getting NHibernate to work with stored procedures that return multiple result sets?

I am working on a project that the lead wishes to use NHibernate and our dba's only want us to read from stored procedures many of which return multiple result sets. I looks to me like NHibernate doesn't support this use case directly, Are there any work arounds / extensions for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069865/nhibernate-multiple-recordsets-from-stored-procedure

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible

Add dummy queries for getting desired result. For example if we want fifth result set from the output of a stored procedure, after the actual query add 4 more dummy query(empty query), then use AddScalar method to retrieve the data using the column name. Example given below is actually retrieving data of column "export_file_line" from 5th and 7th result set

```
var session = GetCurrentSession();
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec SPName @param1=:param1,   @param2=:param2");
query.SetParameter("param1", value1);
query.SetParameter("param2", value2);

var multiResults = session.CreateMultiQuery()
    .Add(query)// More table your procedure returns,more empty SQL query you should add
    .Add(session.CreateSQLQuery(" "))
    .Add(session.CreateSQLQuery(" "))
    .Add(session.CreateSQLQuery(" "))
    .Add(session.CreateSQLQuery(" ")
    .AddScalar("export_file_line", NHibernateUtil.String))// the fifth result set
    .Add(session.CreateSQLQuery(" "))
    .Add(session.CreateSQLQuery(" ")
    .AddScalar("export_file_line", NHibernateUtil.String))// the seventh result set
    .Add(session.CreateSQLQuery(" "))
    .List();

if (multiResults == null || multiResults.Count <= 6 || multiResults[4] == null || multiResults[6] == null) return result;
var headerList = (System.Collections.IList)multiResults[4];
var detailsList = (System.Collections.IList)multiResults[6];
```

Comment: Please explain your code to make it useful for people who stumble upon this answer later on. Pasting code directly, can be very hard to understand.

Comment: Note: CreateMultiQuery is now obsolete and you should use CreateQueryBatch instead

Comment: Nice.  I'm using it on the new CreateQueryBatch and it still works.  For those that use IResultTransformer, I've also found that you can use them on each of the blank CreateSQLQuery objects and it will work e.g. 
query = Session.CreateSQLQuery(" ").SetResultTransformer(new Transformer<T>()), then later on, multiResults.GetResult<T>(queryIndex)

Comment: You legend. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. It feels janky to add "empty" queries though. I'll just add detailed comments

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that NHiberate does not support this.

See here:

[nhibernate multiple recordsets from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069865/nhibernate-multiple-recordsets-from-stored-procedure)

Entity Framework ~kinda~ supports it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj691402

The msdn article name is "Stored Procedures with Multiple Result Sets" (in case the link dies in the future)

The "kinda" is this part of the EntityFramework portion is this -> Your column-names must match your Poco objects property-names **exactly**.

Below is a quote from the msdn article.

*Note:EF does not take any mapping into account when it creates entities using the Translate method. It will simply match column names in the result set with property names on your classes.*

Comment: Just spent 1 week bashing my head against the wall trying to make NHibernate work the same way EF could since several years ago. Had experience with any and all flavors of EF, none of NHibernate. My guess is that the understanding of Reflection in general greatly increased from NHibernate times to EF times. Welp.

Comment: #ormWars are fun!